# Django models.Model all column values end with L?

Tags: python, database, django

In the docs tutorial docs where you use the shell on tutorial 1, it shows you how to look at the values of a model object. When I use `model_object.__dict__` to see all the columns and its values everything ends with L this is making it difficult to pull data from the database because i have to add the `L` when using `filter(), get()`.

#### model code

```
class App(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    downloads = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('pub date', default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

#### python manage.py shell

```
In [11]: app = App.objects.get(title="Game1")

In [12]: app
Out[12]: <app: Game1>  

In [13]: app.__dict__
Out[13]: 
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState at 0x3a20810>,
 'dowloads': 173L,
 'dislikes': 0L,
 'id': 1L,
 'likes': 0L,
 'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 27, 22, 30, 42, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'title': u'Game1'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put L in your calls to `get()` or `filter()`. `L` just denotes that variable is of type long, as opposed to regular integer, but in fact the variable contains just the number, and same applies for database - it stores only the number. Therefore you can use `App.objects.get(id=1)` or `App.objects.filter(downloads__gte=100)` without worrying about whether variable is long or not.

As a matter of fact, python internally appends L when printing longs:

```
In [12]: a = long(12321312)
In [13]: a
Out[13]: 12321312L
```

which does not stop it from comparing longs with regular integerers:

```
In [14]: a > 123
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: Okay, this just thew me off a bit. Thanks